# CSP: child-src and frame-src deprecated

Tags: content-security-policy

1. In CSP v2 **frame-src** was deprecated. **child-src** is recommended to use instead.
2. In CSP v3 **frame-src** in undeprecated and **child-src** is deprecated.
3. Currently (sep 2017) Chrome:

> The 'child-src' directive is deprecated and will be removed in M60, around August 2017. Please use the 'script-src' directive for Workers instead.

So what's correct collection of directives to work in modern (minus 2 versions) browsers? Looks like **frame-src** + **script-src** is enough? But what should be in **script-src** then?

PS: is it even legal to "undeprecate" stuff?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**2018-12-20 update**

`child-src` has in the meantime [been un-deprecated](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/commit/af505e8)… So now neither `frame-src` nor `child-src` are deprecated any longer. But the guidance from the original answer here still holds true:

> So what's correct collection of directives to work in modern (minus 2 versions) browsers?

It seems like the answer to that depends on what exactly you want to specify a policy for.

1. If your needs are simple and so you don’t want to have different policies for `iframe` elements and scripts, then just use `default-src` to specify the same policy for both.
2. If your needs are more complicated and you want a policy for `iframe` elements that’s different than the policy for other resources, than use `frame-src`. Similarly, if you want a policy for scripts that’s different than the policy for other resources, then use `script-src`.
3. If you don’t want a policy for worker scripts different than the policy for other scripts, then you’re fine just providing a `script-src` policy, and can stop there.
4. If you *do* want a policy for worker scripts different than the policy for other scripts, then along with providing a `script-src` policy, provide a `worker-src` policy too. The `worker-src` one won’t effect browsers yet, but will future-proof things for when browsers do add support.

---

See https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/issues/239#issuecomment-336135344 if you’re curious about the rationale for `child-src` being un-deprecated:

> I was hoping other vendors would implement `worker-src` so we could drive down usage of `child-src` and remove it from the platform, but it doesn't look like that's happening quickly enough (removing Chrome's weird fallbacks would break a worker load on 0.006% of page views, which is not huge, but not nothing).

---

**2017-09-04 answer**

It’s even a bit more complicated than what’s described in the question, because the CSP3 spec also introduces [the `worker-src` directive](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#directive-worker-src). But the spec gives [the following guidance](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#changes-from-level-2):

> The `child-src` model has been substantially altered:
>
> 1. The `frame-src` directive, which was deprecated in CSP Level 2, has been undeprecated, but continues to defer to `child-src` if not present (which defers to `default-src` in turn).
> 2. A `worker-src` directive has been added, deferring to `script-src` if not present (which likewise defers to default-src in turn).
> 3. `child-src` is now deprecated.

That’s in https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/, which is an editor’s draft but is what you should always consult for current spec requirements. Reason: You can’t trust https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/ to be up to date (and in general you can’t trust anything under https://www.w3.org/TR to be up to date), and editor’s drafts are what browser implementors actually implement from (they don’t wait to implement until something’s published under https://www.w3.org/TR).

Anyway, the reason the `child-src` directive was deprecated is that [its effect is specified as](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#directive-child-src):

> The **child-src** directive governs the creation of nested browsing contexts (e.g. `<iframe>` and `<frame>` navigations) and Worker execution contexts.

The problem with that in practice is: an `iframe` is very different than a worker script. So that’s why [`worker-src`](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#directive-worker-src) was added and why `frame-src` was un-deprecated (because you really do want a separate directive to specify policies for `iframe` elements), and why `child-src` was deprecated (because you really don’t want to apply one policy to both `iframe` elements and worker scripts).

> So what's correct collection of directives to work in modern (minus 2 versions) browsers?

It seems like the answer to that depends on what exactly you want to specify a policy for.

1. If your needs are simple and so you don’t want to have different policies for `iframe` elements and scripts, then just use `default-src` to specify the same policy for both.
2. If your needs are more complicated and you want a policy for `iframe` elements that’s different than the policy for other resources, than use `frame-src`. Similarly, if you want a policy for scripts that’s different than the policy for other resources, then use `script-src`.
3. If you don’t want a policy for worker scripts different than the policy for other scripts, then you’re fine just providing a `script-src` policy, and can stop there.
4. If you *do* want a policy for worker scripts different than the policy for other scripts, then along with providing a `script-src` policy, provide a `worker-src` policy too. The `worker-src` one won’t effect browsers yet, but will future-proof things for when browsers do add support.

> PS: is it even legal to "undeprecate" stuff?

Yes. Though I can’t remember ever seeing any other spec or working group do that, it was the right thing to do in this case—because the CSP spec authors and working group realized that `child-src` was a mistake, and `frame-src` was actually necessary and it was a mistake to deprecate it.

So they unwound those mistakes—and relatively quickly. And part of why it worked in this case is: `frame-src` wasn’t deprecated long enough for browsers to ever get around to dropping support for it, and also a lot of web developers never got around to using `child-src` to begin with.