# Content Security Policy and iFrames.

Tags: content-security-policy

CSP has frame-src, child-src and frame-ancestors.

frame-src is deprecated in favor of child-src.

child-src and frame-ancestors are for iframes as part of CSP 2.

So I simply want to say iframes are only allowed for origin.

frame-src ‘self’; child-src ‘self’; frame-ancestors ‘self’

so what’s the difference between child-src and frame-ancestors ?

presumable a browser supporting CSP2 takes child-src over frame-src?

Comment: Short answer: Don’t use `child-src`. Longer answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46039068/csp-child-src-and-frame-src-deprecated/46042614#46042614